# Alternatives to jQuery scrollTo for iPad love

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, jquery-animate, scrollto

I'm sure we've all read [iPad Flicker on auto scroll using JQuery and Scrollto plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125805/ipad-flicker-on-auto-scroll-using-jquery-and-scrollto-plugin) before. Here it is a year and a half later and I have yet to find an elegant solution.

I'm using [scrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) and [localScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html) to animate a set of nav anchors and it is awful on an iPad. After some simplification, I've found that the issue is caused by scrolling on both the X and Y axes. If I instead stack them vertically I skip the iPad freak out.

Unfortunately I'm not authorized to make such design alterations and I feel it's time we all gather together and vanquish this beast anyway.

So, what's the latest? Anybody make a modular, XY compatible, hash-scrolling, easing algorithm champion?