# jquery.ScrollTo not working correctly on iphone nor ipad

Tags: jquery, scroll

Here's a webpage: http://kafe.zum.kz

I am using latest version of jquery.ScrollTo.min.js. However, it's not working correctly on iPhone 5 nor latest iPad.

You will see a menu on the top:

[image]

When you click e.g. on "КОНТАКТЫ" it will scroll down to div with `id="contacts"` but when you click after "КОНТАКТЫ" to "НАШЕ МЕНЮ" it firstly goes to the very top of the page only then it goes to div with `id="menu"`. That behavior is met only on iphone & ipad, on android or windows is fine.

It should work like this: you click "КОНТАКТЫ" it scrolls down to this section, then while on this section you're clicking "НАШЕ МЕНЮ" it just scroll up to the "НАШЕ МЕНЮ" section.

here's my js:

```
// main menu scroll to section
var boks = ['.menu-469', '.menu-471', '.menu-470', '.menu-472', '.menu-473', '.menu-474', '.menu-475', '.menu-476', '.menu-477'];
var element = ['#about', '#zum-slider', '#afisha', '#photos', '#zumenu', '#hotdeals', '#partners', '#karta', '#contacts'];

for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        $('#main-menu li' + boks[i]).click(function() {
            $(window).scrollTo($(element[i]), 800);
            //alert(element[i]);
        });
    }(i));
}
```

I hope for your help guys. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE1.** found answer at: [iPad Flicker on auto scroll using JQuery and Scrollto plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125805/ipad-flicker-on-auto-scroll-using-jquery-and-scrollto-plugin)

Going to try it out.

Comment: I had used `scroller_id.scrollTo(0,0);`  which worked fine in both android and ios.

Comment: You mean you have used the same library jquery.ScrollTo and it worked  fine in both OS? Have you checked my webpage in IOS to see that behaviour?

Comment: Not having mac or iphone now. But yes, scrollTo worked fine in ios for me.

Comment: Any ideas what might be causing it to go to the top, only then to required section?

Comment: Nope :/ sorry. may be $(window). but not sure

Comment: You mean i can try to use $(document) instead of window?

Comment: Nope, scroller id. I had used that. You must have initialized iscroll and it must have id.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47299/discussion-between-heihachi-and-mystic-magic)

Answer (score 1):

You should include `{axis: 'y'}` in your options object. Also be sure that you have not enabled interrupt option. You can test this with `{interrupt: false}`.